# Cannot make two argument elseif work correctly (PHP, file upload)

Tags: php, file-upload, if-statement

Whenever i upload a jpg or png file that is above the 1mb limit, the script displays the first else if where it states that both file format and the file size do not match the criteria. Where as I want it to recognize jpg and png formats as the correct ones. Other variants (different filetypes, jpgs <1mb do work as intented)
html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Post your images</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
Ttile: <input type="text" name="title" id="title"> <br>
Watermark: <input type="text" name="watermark" id="watermark"> <br>
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

        <title>Gallery</title></head>
    <body>
    <?php
        $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
      {

      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {

        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }

      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "File Type: " . $extension . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
         "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
          echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
      }
    elseif(
           ($_FILES["file"]["type"] !== "image/jpeg")
       and ($_FILES["file"]["type"] !== "image/jpg")
       and ($_FILES["file"]["type"] !== "image/png")
       and ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
       )
      {
        echo "Wrong file format and too big file<br>";
      }



    elseif(($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)){
        echo "File is too big, maximum size is 1MB";
    }
    else{
         echo "File format not supported! Supported files formats are png i jpg.";
    }

    ?> 
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `if (condition criteria)` then to here `if not then` go here `if not not` go here... It does not make sense, multiple ifstatements require conditions

Comment: Can you tell me how to make those? I am quite a rookie in the subject

Answer (score 0):

```
 (...) and ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
```

Didn't you forget about doing `>` instead of `<` ?

Comment: The script stops displaying anything if i do that, i have already tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try,

```
     <?php
            $allowedExts = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            $extension = end($temp);
            if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
            || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
            && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 1048576)
            && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
              {

              if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                {

                echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
                }

              else
                {
                echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
                echo "File Type: " . $extension . "<br>";
                echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                 "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }
              } 
            elseif($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 1048576){
                echo "File is too big, maximum size is 1MB";
            }
            else{
                 echo "File format not supported! Supported files formats are png i jpg.";
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: I want the script to distinguish between files that are too big, wrong file type and have both of these things wrong. What i mean is i want the script to give me 3 different errors incase it goes wrong.